# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CalendarEvent>''

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to application block.

I am trying to get data from database. Following is the code snap.

JsonResponse.ashx:

```cs
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpContext _context = HttpContext.Current;

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    int user_id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"]);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    start = start.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["start"]));
    end = end.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["end"]));       
    String result = String.Empty;

    result += "[";

    List<int> idList = new List<int>();
    foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end, user_id))
    {
        result += convertCalendarEventIntoString(cevent);
        idList.Add(cevent.id);
    }

    if (result.EndsWith(","))
    {
        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
    }

    result += "]";
    //store list of event ids in Session, so that it can be accessed in web methods
    context.Session["idList"] = idList;

    context.Response.Write(result);
}

private String convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent)
{
    String allDay = "true";
    if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
    {

        if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
        {
            allDay = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            allDay = "false";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
            && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
        {
            allDay = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            allDay = "false";
        }
    }
    return    "{" +
              "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
              "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
              "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
              "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
              "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
                "user_id:" + cevent.user_id + "," +
              "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'" +

              "},";
}
```

DA:

```cs
public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, int user_id)
{

    List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();

    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[3];
    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@start", start);
    sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@end", end);
    sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@user_id", user_id);
    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString,CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetData", sqlParam);
}
```

sqlhelper:

```cs
public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
{
    //create a command and prepare it for execution
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
    PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (SqlTransaction)null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);

    //create the DataAdapter & DataSet
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc.
    da.Fill(ds);

    // detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again.         
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    //return the dataset
    return ds;                      
}
```

I am getting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.

I am unable to understand what is the problem.

Comment: `ExecuteDataset` returns `DataSet` which you immediately try to return as `List<CalendarEvent>` from `getEvents`. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `getEvents` method, you need to iterate through the records in the dataset and fill in the list that you would return in this method.

```
var dataset = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString,CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetData", sqlParam);

foreach (var row in ds.Tables["FooTable"].Rows)
{
     events.Add(new CalendarEvent(...));
}

return events;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you try to return a dataset as List, which it isn't.
You need to convert the dataset to a list. A possible solution would be to change the getEvents method to something like this ->

```
public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, int user_id)
{

    List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();

    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[3];
    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@start", start);
    sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@end", end);
    sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@user_id", user_id);
    var ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString,CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetData", sqlParam);
    return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(datarow => new CalendarEvent{ Title = datarow.Field<string>("Title), /*the rest of your params*/}).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this piece of code:

```
public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, int user_id)
{
    List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();
    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[3];
    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@start", start);
    sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@end", end);
    sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@user_id", user_id);
    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString,CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetData", sqlParam);
}
```

You defined the type of this method as `List<CalenderEvent>` but you return a `DataSet`. 
I do not know which datatables are contained in your dataset, but I assume there is one which represents your calenderevents.

This means you need to extract the data you want from your dataset and make a list out of it. Assuming there is one table in your dataset your new method would look something like this:

```
public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, int user_id)
{
    List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();
    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[3];
    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@start", start);
    sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@end", end);
    sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@user_id", user_id);


    var data = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString,CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetData", sqlParam);
    events = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new CalenderEvent 
                                         {
                                           //using dummy properties because I dont know 
                                           //your class
                                           Property1 = r.Field<string>("Column1"),
                                           Property2 = r.Field<string>("column2"),
                                           //...
                                         }).ToList();
    return events;
}
```

Comment: .Select(r => new CalenderEvent 
                                         {
                                           //using dummy properties because I dont know 
                                           //your class
                                           Property1 = r.Field<string>("Column1"),
                                           Property2 = r.Field<string>("column2"),
                                           //...
                                         }).ToList();

Comment: What did you want to tell me Monica?

Comment: => operator not supported....i am using vs 2005.error occuring in this portion,  events = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new CalenderEvent {
                                           //using dummy properties because I dont know 
                                           //your class
                                           Property1 = r.Field<string>("Column1"),
    }).ToList();

Comment: Oh! Of course. I copuld'nt know that. Linq and lambda expressions are not supported in your version. you should go with a foreach loop then like Szymon suggested and please edit your question to refelct the fact that you use VS2005. A lot of people these days are spoiled LINQ-brats, me included